# Java separate logger configuration for each ID

Tags: java, slf4j, java.util.logging

I am looking forward to actually configure a logger that should be created for different IDs.

My application is very huge and there are nearly 20 users accessing the application at a time so when they get any exceptions it is becoming very difficult to check in the log what actually went wrong.

So i want to create a logger in such a way that its generates the log on the ids (unique) that i provide.( i.e i mean separate logger for each ID)

Could anyone help me how this can be achieved .

Thanks

Comment: what is the logging stack exactly?

Comment: Check out Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC): http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

Comment: Log4j has the NDC http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html

Answer (score 0):

Logback's [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) is tailor made for this purpose.